# Need to access variables from child during SIGCHLD handler

Tags: c, signals, parent-child

I'm prefacing this by stating that it is a homework assignment and I'm stuck while writing the SIGCHLD handler. I need to access variables within the child process.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


#define TEXT_LEN 10
#define NUM_RESCUE_PLOWS 4
#define NUM_VICTIMS_TO_RESCUE 40


/*  PURPOSE:  To keep trap of the number of victims that have been rescued.
 */
int numRescuedVictims = 0;



/*  PURPOSE:  To keep track of the process id's of the rescuing snow plows.
 */
pid_t plowPid[NUM_RESCUE_PLOWS];


/*  PURPOSE:  To note that at least one child plow has finished.  Reports the
 *process id and the number of victims rescued for each child plow.
 *'sigNum' tells the signal number.  No return value
 */
//  You may want to define a SIGCHLD listener here
//  It should have a loop that wait()s for children and
//  and prints how many victims each has rescued.
void listenSIGCHLD(int sig)
{
  int status;
  pid_t pidWait;
  while((pidWait = wait(&status)) > 0)
    printf("Plow %d rescued %d victim(s)", plowId, numVictimsRescued);
}


/*  PURPOSE:  To handle being informed of a rescued victim.  'sigNum' tells
 *signal number.  No return value.
 */
//  You may want to define a SIGUSR1 listener here
//  It increments 'numRescuedVictims' and prints the total number rescued victims
void listenSIGUSR1(int sig)
{
  numRescuedVictims += &numVictimsRescued;
  printf("We've rescued %d victims!" numRescuedVictims);
}


/*  PURPOSE:  To make 'NUM_RESCUE_PLOWS' processes to run 'rescuingPlow' to
 *rescue stuck victims, and then tell them to quit after all
 *'NUM_VICTIMS_TO_RESCUE' victims have been rescued.  Ignores parameters.
 *Returns 'EXIT_SUCCESS' to OS.
 */
int main ()
{

  //  I.  Applicability validity check:


  //  II.  Rescue victims:

  //  II.A.  Install 'SIGUSR1' handler:
  signal(SIGUSR1, listenSIGUSR1);

  // Install 'SIGUSR1' handler
  //  Install your SIGCHLD handler here
  signal(SIGCHLD, listenSIGCHLD);

  //  II.B.  Tell NUM_RESCUE_PLOWS plows to start rescuing the victims:

  int i;
  int myPid= getpid();

  for  (i = 0;  i < NUM_RESCUE_PLOWS;  i++)
    {
      //  Do a fork() and save it in plowPid[i]
      plowPid[i] = fork();
      //  If plowPid[i] is less than 0 then do:
      if(plowPid[i] < 0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr,"Dude, your system is WAY to busy to play rescuer!\n");
      return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

      //  If plowPid[i] is equal to 0 then do:
      else if(plowPid[i] == 0)
    {
      char pidText[TEXT_LEN];
      char indexText[TEXT_LEN];
    }
      snprintf(pidText,TEXT_LEN,"%d",myPid);
      snprintf(indexText,TEXT_LEN,"%d",i);
      execl("./rescuingPlow","rescuingPlow",pidText,indexText,NULL);
      fprintf(stderr,"Dude, somebody stole my plow!!\n");
      return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


  //  II.C.  Wait until all victims have been rescued:

  while  (numRescuedVictims < NUM_VICTIMS_TO_RESCUE)
    {
      sleep(1);
      printf("Searching for victims . . .\n");
    }


  //  III.  Finished:

  //  Loop to send SIGTERM to all NUM_RESCUE_PLOWS plow processes
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RESCUE_PLOWS; i++)
    {
      kill(plowPid[i], SIGTERM);
    }
  int toSleep= NUM_RESCUE_PLOWS;

  //  sleep() can be interrupted by SIGCHLD.  Whenever it is interrupted
  //  it returns the number of seconds that still remain on its alarm
  //  clock.  Let's wait until it has slept its full amount incase it
  //  was prematured interrupted by SIGCHLD.
  do
    {
      toSleep= sleep(toSleep);
    }
  while  (toSleep > 0);

  printf("Ready for the NEXT snow storm!\n");
  return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

`

and here's what's going to end up being the spawned processes. Although I haven't worked through that yet.

```
/*
 *  rescuingPlow.c
 *
 *  Compile with $ gcc rescuingPlow.c -o rescuingPlow
 */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


/*  PURPOSE:  To keep track of the number of victims that this process
 *  rescued.
 */
int numVictimsRescued   = 0;



/*  PURPOSE:  To return the number of victims rescued to the OS.  'sigNum'
 *  tells the signal number.  No return value.
 */
//  You may want to write a SIGTERM handling function
//  that returns to the OS 'numVictimsRescued'.



/*  PURPOSE:  To rescue victims at random intervals and inform parent process
 *  by sending it SIGUSR1 until receiving SIGTERM.  First parameter (after
 *  program name) tells parent's process id.  Second parameter tells this
 *  plow's index.
 */
int main    (int argc, char* argv[])
{

  //  I.  Applicability validity check:

  pid_t parentPID;
  int   plowId;

  if  (argc < 3)
  {
    fprintf(stderr,"USAGE: rescuingPlow <parentPID> <plowId>\n");
    return(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  parentPID = atoi(argv[1]);
  plowId    = atoi(argv[2]);


  //  II.  Rescuing victims until told to stop:

  //  II.A.  Install signal handler:

  //  Install your SIGTERM handler here
  srand(plowId);  //  Uniquely initialize random number generator so they act independently of each other


  //  II.B.  Rescue victims:

  //  Write an endless loop that:
  //  (1) Does 'sleep((rand() % 6) + 1);'
  //  (2) Increments 'numVictimsRescued'
  //  (3) Does 'printf("Plow %d rescued %d victim(s)!\n",plowId,numVictimsRescued);'
  //  (4) Send 'SIGUSR1' to 'parentPID'


  //  III.  Finished:

  return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I'm not completely sure where I'm going with this or how to deal with that. I'm pretty confident I can deal with most of the other problems that exist.

Comment: OT: Do not use `printf()` from a signal handler, as it is not necessarly save to call it from there. The same applies to many other functions. In fact onls a small subset of functions is defined to be implemented in a async signal save way. For of list of the latter please see `man 7 signal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using some IPC mechanics the child can only pass a value of 8 bits to the parent process.

Those 8 bits are send by the child as parameter to the call to `exit()` and receive by the parent by applying the macro `WEXITSTATUS()` to the value of `status` as returned by a successful call to  `wait()` or `waitpid()`. Please see `man 2 exit` and `man 2 wait` for details.

If I remember correctly 8 bits are the minimum as defined by the standard. Some implementations might allow more bits.

**Update:**

Example on how to use `wait()`:

```
int child_exit_code = -1;
int status = -1;
pid_t pid = wait(&status);
if (-1 != pid)
  child_exit_code = WEXITSTATUS(status);
```

Comment: So basically set the status equal to whatever I need to send when the child process ends then? And use 'WEXITSTATUS()' to get what I need?

Comment: @nateperrone: If "whatever" you need isn't more then 8 bits wide, does not need to be more accurate then 2^8=256 different values, this should do, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shmget` to allocate shared memory.

Use it before forking, and then the allocated memory will be accessible to both child and parent.
The child can store whatever it wants there, and the parent will read it.